# ZipKin UI Fail To Load Trace From MySQL

Tags: zipkin

I am facing an issue where in the ZipKin UI is failing to load in the traces from MySQL.

It is giving me below mentioned error on UI -

> Error executing query: SQL [select distinct `zipkin_spans`.`trace_id`
>   from `zipkin_spans` join `zipkin_annotations` on
>   (`zipkin_spans`.`trace_id` = `zipkin_annotations`.`trace_id` and
>   `zipkin_spans`.`id` = `zipkin_annotations`.`span_id`) where
>   (`zipkin_spans`.`start_ts` between ? and ? and
>   `zipkin_annotations`.`endpoint_service_name` = ?) order by
>   `zipkin_spans`.`start_ts` desc limit ?]; Expression #1 of ORDER BY
>   clause is not in SELECT list, references column
>   'zipkin.zipkin_spans.start_ts' which is not in SELECT list; this is
>   incompatible with DISTINCT

I see below exception on ZipKin Server -

```
2016-12-03 20:55:47.206 ERROR 67584 --- [nio-9411-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select distinct `zipkin_spans`.`trace_id` from `zipkin_spans` join `zipkin_annotations` on (`zipkin_spans`.`trace_id` = `zipkin_annotations`.`trace_id` and `zipkin_spans`.`id` = `zipkin_annotations`.`span_id`) where (`zipkin_spans`.`start_ts` between ? and ? and `zipkin_annotations`.`endpoint_service_name` = ?) order by `zipkin_spans`.`start_ts` desc limit ?]; Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'zipkin.zipkin_spans.start_ts' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'zipkin.zipkin_spans.start_ts' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:194) ~[jooq-3.8.5.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:269) ~[jooq-3.8.5.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:348) ~[jooq-3.8.5.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:312) ~[jooq-3.8.5.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:393) ~[jooq-3.8.5.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2748) ~[jooq-3.8.5.jar:na]
    at zipkin.storage.mysql.MySQLSpanStore.getTraces(MySQLSpanStore.java:164) ~[zipkin-storage-mysql-1.13.1.jar:na]
    at zipkin.storage.mysql.MySQLSpanStore.getTraces(MySQLSpanStore.java:236) ~[zipkin-storage-mysql-1.13.1.jar:na]
    at zipkin.server.ZipkinQueryApiV1.getTraces(ZipkinQueryApiV1.java:105) ~[zipkin-server-1.13.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

My ZipKin Server Configuration is a below -

```
application.yml

server:   
  port: 9411

spring:   
  application:
    name: zipkin-server   datasource:
    schema: classpath:/mysql.sql
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zipkin?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    initialize: true
    continue-on-error: true   sleuth:
    enabled: false

zipkin:   
   storage:
      type: mysql


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZipkinServer
public class ZipkinApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I query the MySQL schema, I can see the record being populated in "zipkin.zipkin_spans and zipkin.zipkin_annotations" table.

But when I try to load the Zipkin UI, it give me above error on UI.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with MySQL 5.7 and more recently resolved. You can try latest Zipkin.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to load and startup ZipKin using MySQL as store using latest ZipKin version.